# How to get rows from SysListView32 using ControlListView()?

Tags: c#, autoit-c#-wrapper, syslistview32

My code to select the SysListView32 is working fine:

```
string text = strings.au3.ControlListView(strings.TerminalName, "", "SysListView321", "SelectAll","","");
string text2 = strings.au3.ControlListView(strings.TerminalName, "", "SysListView322", "SelectAll", "", "");
```

I want to get the rows of the SysListView32. I tried `GetText` but it is always returning 0.

```
string Aaasa = strings.au3.ControlListView(strings.TerminalName, "", "SysListView321", "GetText", "", "");
string Aaasa = strings.au3.ControlListView(strings.TerminalName, "", "SysListView322", "GetText", "", "");
```

Is there any way I can use AutoIt to get all the rows (Ex-the last tradetime, %change, volume, symbol). I need to fetch data from the 2 lists in the application simultaneously every second.

Answer (score 0):

from AutoItX.chm

> "GetText", Item, SubItem
>
> Returns the text of a given item/subitem.

```
string Aaasa = strings.au3.ControlListView(strings.TerminalName, "", "SysListView321", "GetText", 0, 0);
string Aaasa = strings.au3.ControlListView(strings.TerminalName, "", "SysListView322", "GetText", 1, 0);
```

You should provide integeres not string as a 5th and 6th parameters

After comment I think it should look like:

```
string Aaasa = strings.au3.ControlListView(strings.TerminalName, "", "SysListView321", "GetText", "0", "0");
string Aaasa = strings.au3.ControlListView(strings.TerminalName, "", "SysListView322", "GetText", "1", "0");
```

Comment: But the method what is inbuilt in autoitdll is string ControlListView(string strTitle, string strText, string strControl, string strCommand, string strExtra1, string strExtra2);

Comment: so at least provide number as astring `......, "GetText", "1", "0");`  but not emty string as you do `....., "GetText", "", "");` as "" is used when option is not required, but when you use "GetText" then you must provide valid option values.